# How to make an LSTM Bidirectional?

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, bidirectional, pytorch-lightning

**Question:**
What changes to `LSTMClassifier` do I need to make, in order to have this LSTM work bidirectionally?

I'm basing my amendments on this [disscuss.pytorch.org response](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-make-an-lstm-bidirectional/142928/7?u=danielbellhv).

---

I *think* the problem is in `forward()`. It learns from the **last state** of LSTM neural network, by slicing:

```py
tag_space = self.classifier(lstm_out[:,-1,:])
```

Do I need to sum up or concatenate the values of the 2 layers/ directions?

---

Working Code:

```py
from argparse import ArgumentParser

import torchmetrics
import pytorch_lightning as pl
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class LSTMClassifier(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, 
        num_classes, 
        batch_size=10,
        embedding_dim=100, 
        hidden_dim=50, 
        vocab_size=128):

        super(LSTMClassifier, self).__init__()

        initrange = 0.1

        self.num_labels = num_classes
        n = len(self.num_labels)
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        
        self.num_layers = 1

        self.word_embeddings = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        self.word_embeddings.weight.data.uniform_(-initrange, initrange)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=embedding_dim, hidden_size=hidden_dim, num_layers=self.num_layers, batch_first=True, bidirectional=True)  # !
        #self.classifier = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, self.num_labels[0])
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(2 * hidden_dim, self.num_labels[0])  # !


    def repackage_hidden(h):
        """Wraps hidden states in new Tensors, to detach them from their history."""

        if isinstance(h, torch.Tensor):
            return h.detach()
        else:
            return tuple(repackage_hidden(v) for v in h)


    def forward(self, sentence, labels=None):
        embeds = self.word_embeddings(sentence)
        # lstm_out, _ = self.lstm(embeds)  # lstm_out - 2 tensors, _ - hidden layer
        lstm_out, hidden = self.lstm(embeds)
        
        # Calculate number of directions
        self.num_directions = 2 if self.lstm.bidirectional == True else 1
        
        # Extract last hidden state
        # final_state = hidden.view(self.num_layers, self.num_directions, self.batch_size, self.hidden_dim)[-1]
        final_state = hidden[0].view(self.num_layers, self.num_directions, self.batch_size, self.hidden_dim)[-1]
        # Handle directions
        final_hidden_state = None
        if self.num_directions == 1:
            final_hidden_state = final_state.squeeze(0)
        elif self.num_directions == 2:
            h_1, h_2 = final_state[0], final_state[1]
            # final_hidden_state = h_1 + h_2               # Add both states (requires changes to the input size of first linear layer + attention layer)
            final_hidden_state = torch.cat((h_1, h_2), 1)  # Concatenate both states

        print("len(final_hidden_state)", len(final_hidden_state))
        print("len(labels)", len(labels))

        # tag_space = self.classifier(hidden[:,0,:] + hidden[:,-1,:])  # !  # torch.flip(lstm_out[:,-1,:], [0, 1]) - 1 tensor
        logits = F.log_softmax(final_hidden_state, dim=1)  # tag_space
        loss = None
        if labels:
            loss = F.cross_entropy(logits.view(-1, self.num_labels[0]), labels[0].view(-1))
        return loss, logits


class LSTMTaggerModel(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(
        self,
        num_classes,
        class_map,
        from_checkpoint=False,
        model_name='last.ckpt',
        learning_rate=3e-6,
        **kwargs,
    ):

        super().__init__()
        self.save_hyperparameters()
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.model = LSTMClassifier(num_classes=num_classes)
        # self.model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_name), strict=False)  # !
        self.class_map = class_map
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.valid_acc = torchmetrics.Accuracy()
        self.valid_f1 = torchmetrics.F1()


    def forward(self, *input, **kwargs):
        return self.model(*input, **kwargs)

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y_true = batch
        loss, _ = self(x, labels=y_true)
        self.log('train_loss', loss)
        return loss

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y_true = batch
        _, y_pred = self(x, labels=y_true)
        preds = torch.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
        self.valid_acc(preds, y_true[0])
        self.log('val_acc', self.valid_acc, prog_bar=True)
        self.valid_f1(preds, y_true[0])
        self.log('f1', self.valid_f1, prog_bar=True)     

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        'Prepare optimizer and schedule (linear warmup and decay)'
        opt = torch.optim.Adam(params=self.parameters(), lr=self.learning_rate)
        sch = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CosineAnnealingLR(opt, T_max=10)
        return [opt], [sch]

    def training_epoch_end(self, training_step_outputs):
        avg_loss = torch.tensor([x['loss']
                                 for x in training_step_outputs]).mean()
        self.log('train_loss', avg_loss)
        print(f'###score: train_loss### {avg_loss}')

    def validation_epoch_end(self, val_step_outputs):
        acc = self.valid_acc.compute()
        f1 = self.valid_f1.compute()
        self.log('val_score', acc)
        self.log('f1', f1)
        print(f'###score: val_score### {acc}')

    def add_model_specific_args(parent_parser):
        parser = parent_parser.add_argument_group("OntologyTaggerModel")       
        parser = ArgumentParser(parents=[parent_parser], add_help=False)
        parser.add_argument("--learning_rate", default=2e-3, type=float)
        return parent_parser
```

Runtime:

```
Global seed set to 42
GPU available: False, used: False
TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores

  | Name      | Type           | Params
---------------------------------------------
0 | model     | LSTMClassifier | 77.4 K
1 | valid_acc | Accuracy       | 0     
2 | valid_f1  | F1             | 0     
---------------------------------------------
77.4 K    Trainable params
0         Non-trainable params
77.4 K    Total params
0.310     Total estimated model params size (MB)
Validation sanity check: 0it [00:00, ?it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-3f817f701f20> in <module>
     11     """.split()
     12 
---> 13 run_training(args)

<ipython-input-5-bb0d8b014e32> in run_training(input)
     66         shutil.copyfile(labels_file_orig, labels_file_cp)
     67     trainer = pl.Trainer.from_argparse_args(args, callbacks=[checkpoint_callback], logger=loggers)
---> 68     trainer.fit(model, dm)
     69     model_file = os.path.join(args.modeldir, 'last.ckpt')
     70     trainer.save_checkpoint(model_file, weights_only=True)

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in fit(self, model, train_dataloader, val_dataloaders, datamodule)
    497 
    498         # dispath `start_training` or `start_testing` or `start_predicting`
--> 499         self.dispatch()
    500 
    501         # plugin will finalized fitting (e.g. ddp_spawn will load trained model)

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in dispatch(self)
    544 
    545         else:
--> 546             self.accelerator.start_training(self)
    547 
    548     def train_or_test_or_predict(self):

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/accelerator.py in start_training(self, trainer)
     71 
     72     def start_training(self, trainer):
---> 73         self.training_type_plugin.start_training(trainer)
     74 
     75     def start_testing(self, trainer):

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/training_type/training_type_plugin.py in start_training(self, trainer)
    112     def start_training(self, trainer: 'Trainer') -> None:
    113         # double dispatch to initiate the training loop
--> 114         self._results = trainer.run_train()
    115 
    116     def start_testing(self, trainer: 'Trainer') -> None:

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in run_train(self)
    605             self.progress_bar_callback.disable()
    606 
--> 607         self.run_sanity_check(self.lightning_module)
    608 
    609         # set stage for logging

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in run_sanity_check(self, ref_model)
    858 
    859             # run eval step
--> 860             _, eval_results = self.run_evaluation(max_batches=self.num_sanity_val_batches)
    861 
    862             self.on_sanity_check_end()

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in run_evaluation(self, max_batches, on_epoch)
    723                 # lightning module methods
    724                 with self.profiler.profile("evaluation_step_and_end"):
--> 725                     output = self.evaluation_loop.evaluation_step(batch, batch_idx, dataloader_idx)
    726                     output = self.evaluation_loop.evaluation_step_end(output)
    727 

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/evaluation_loop.py in evaluation_step(self, batch, batch_idx, dataloader_idx)
    164             model_ref._current_fx_name = "validation_step"
    165             with self.trainer.profiler.profile("validation_step"):
--> 166                 output = self.trainer.accelerator.validation_step(args)
    167 
    168         # capture any logged information

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/accelerator.py in validation_step(self, args)
    175 
    176         with self.precision_plugin.val_step_context(), self.training_type_plugin.val_step_context():
--> 177             return self.training_type_plugin.validation_step(*args)
    178 
    179     def test_step(self, args):

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/training_type/training_type_plugin.py in validation_step(self, *args, **kwargs)
    129 
    130     def validation_step(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 131         return self.lightning_module.validation_step(*args, **kwargs)
    132 
    133     def test_step(self, *args, **kwargs):

<ipython-input-17-542f29e75b1a> in validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx)
    104     def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    105         x, y_true = batch
--> 106         _, y_pred = self(x, labels=y_true)
    107         preds = torch.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
    108         self.valid_acc(preds, y_true[0])

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

<ipython-input-17-542f29e75b1a> in forward(self, *input, **kwargs)
     94 
     95     def forward(self, *input, **kwargs):
---> 96         return self.model(*input, **kwargs)
     97 
     98     def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

<ipython-input-17-542f29e75b1a> in forward(self, sentence, labels)
     67         loss = None
     68         if labels:
---> 69             loss = F.cross_entropy(logits.view(-1, self.num_labels[0]), labels[0].view(-1))
     70         return loss, logits
     71 

RuntimeError: shape '[-1, 38]' is invalid for input of size 1000
```

Comment: [discuss.pytorch.org post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-make-an-lstm-bidirectional/142928)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to load a pretrained model (which uses an unidirectional LSTM) into a model which has a bidirectional LSTM in its state dict. There are several things you can do here, as there are innate differences between your pretrained state dict and your bidirectional state dict:

1. Definitely use `model.load_state_dict(model_params,strict=False)` (see [this link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/does-model-load-state-dict-strict-false-ignore-new-parameters-introduced-in-my-models-constructor/84539)). This will stop the complaining when you use a model that's different to what you're trying to learn. It means that your forward pass will be pretrained but not your backward pass.
2. If you do this ^ you will need to sum or otherwise condense the final time steps for the forward and backward case because the classifier will then have a different shape otherwise. `strict=False` though will ignore this, so only do this if you care about having a pretrained first layer in your classifier.
3. If you don't want to do the above two, you can copy the weights for `model.lstm.weight_ih_l0_reverse` and other missing parameters from the forward direction in the state dict, as it's just a python dictionary. It is not ideal because obviously the forward and backward pass will learn different things, but will stop the error and be in a reasonably good initialisation space. You will still have the same error in two though where your LSTM output is twice as big as it was.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. The only change that works is appending `self.model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_name),strict=False)` to another class `LSTMClassifier(num_classes=num_classes)`.  <- Regardless of that, appending `bidirectional=True` always crashes.

Comment: I do need to add `bidirectional=True` but I imagine it's expected that I must update this line in `forward()`: `tag_space = self.classifier(lstm_out[:,-1,:])`. Unfortunately, [parameter documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html) does not detail what to else I should change to accompany.

Comment: If you're doing bidirectional it doesn't make sense to use the last output because in the reverse direction that would be the first timestep. I would advise you to use either the cell (c_n) output or hidden state (h_n) output. You'll need to scale your size of your `self.classifier` to match the number of layers (if you just have one just multiply it by two, this will not be loaded when you use `.load_state_dict(..,strict=False)` because the sizes won't match).

Comment: AFAIK, you can only get hidden values from the last layer. However, as you've said, the same last layer would be the input/ first layer for the other direction. But `lstm_out[:,-1,:]` x2 theoretically is only useful for shape... which shouldn't matter considering `strict=False`. I find this issue so odd, considering `bidirectional` is a parameter offered.

Comment: Yes, adding two layers together will not change the size? You need to increase the size of the subsequent layer `self.classifier = nn.Linear(2 * hidden_dim, self.num_labels[0])`